# d3 integration to openlayers without npm

Tags: d3.js, openlayers, openlayers-6

I am trying to recreate d3 integration to ol from this example: https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/d3.html but without npm.
I have managed to change most of the imported variables to ol. like:

```
fromLonLat => ol.proj.fromLonLat,
```

but seem to stuck with `SourceState.READY` (line 29 in the example). I get error "Cannot read property 'getState' of null" whatever I try, can't modify `import SourceState from 'ol/source/State';` to anything acceptable.

I have also tried changing layer setup adding source

```
{features: topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties)}
```

to:

```
{source: new ol.source.ImageCanvas({
    features: topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties),
  })  
}
```

}

Comment: You can simply use the string value `'ready'` https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_source_State.html

Comment: Thanks @Mike!!! Simple as that... The error message is gone and it is working. Thanks a lot